# Understanding the definition of a set with $C^k$ boundary and of the outward pointing normal vector field

Tags: calculus, analysis

Consider the following excerpt from Evans book.

[image]

I don't understand these definitions. Can some please **illustrate them on an example**, so that I can figure out how to work with them.

A negative example may be more illustrative, i.e. a set $U$ such that $\partial U$ **isn't** $ C^1$. Especially the second definition is unclear to me, since $\nu^i$ is nowhere actually defined.

Comment: $\nu^{i}$ is computed dependent on the smooth boundary. It's usually not able to be computed..but in cases where the boundary can be parameterized, it can be, thought of by computing the gradient divided by it's norm. This is part of the reason why we come up with the corrector function when we have to compute the green's function for the poisson equation later on. We never usually have information about the solution on the boundary.

Comment: @DaveNine That's some terrific info. Could you maybe post a simple example, where can be computed ? How does a formal definition of $\nu$ look like? Because Evans just defines it using words. I would award bounty for your answer once I can, because this stuff is very important to me.

Comment: How about $U$ the interior of a square? Then the boundary of $U$ is continuous, but not smooth ($C^1$) at the corners.

Comment: @JohnD Well, being not $C^1$ because it has corners is intuitively plausible, but I need to know where precisely the *above definition* fails

Comment: How would you define the normal vector at the corners of the square? Think about what it means to be the normal vector there... And why a lack of $C^1$ is a problem...

Comment: @JohnD I can't parse that. In the above definition if is *defined* what it means to be $C^1$ (and I'm having a hard time checking that definition). So how can the lack of what is defined be a problem ? And for what would it be a problem ?

Answer (score 8):

The definition says, geometrically, that the boundary of $U$ is locally the graph of a function of class $C^{k}$, i.e., a sufficiently small piece of $U$ near a boundary point $x_{0}$ is (possibly after re-indexing coordinates) the super-level set
$$
F(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n-1}, x_{n}) := x_{n} - \gamma(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n-1}) > 0.
$$

For example, the function $\gamma(x) = |x|x^{k}$ is of class $C^{k}$ but not of class $C^{k+1}$, so the (unbounded) region
$$
U = \{(x, y) \text{ in } \mathbf{R}^{2} : y - \gamma(x) > 0\}
$$
has boundary of class $C^{k}$, but not of class $C^{k+1}$. (At most points the boundary is real-analytic, but this example should convey the idea. If you have "more interesting" examples of $C^{k}$ functions, you can cook up correspondingly more interesting regions.)

If $\partial U$ is of class $C^{1}$, then by definition a small piece of $\partial U$ may be written as the graph of a $C^{1}$ function. Consequently, at each boundary point $x_{0}$, there is a well-defined tangent space $T_{x_{0}}$, of dimension $(n - 1)$; the outward unit normal $\nu(x_{0})$ is the unique unit vector orthogonal to $T_{x_{0}}$ and satisfying the directional derivative condition $\nu(F) < 0$, with $F$ a local defining function for the boundary, as above. Geometrically, $\nu(x_{0})$ spans the orthogonal complement of $T_{x_{0}}$ and points toward the exterior of $U$, where $F < 0$.

Comment: That's a great answer. I still have some trouble with $\nu$ though (specifically I don't understand if your $F$ from the last paragraph is a different $F$ than above and, in either case, why its $<0$ outside of $U$). Could you please, to dispel these things,  add an (short, easy) example, where on can explicitly calculate $\nu$ ?

Comment: @pink_pyjamas: The two $F$'s are the same. :) The most familiar example (real-analytic, not $C^{k}$) is perhaps the unit disk in the plane, defined by the inequality $x^{2}+y^{2}<1$. Near a boundary point with $y<0$, we can write (a sufficiently small piece of) the boundary circle as the graph $y=-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}=\gamma(x)$, and introduce $F(x,y)=y+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$, so that $F(x,y)>0$ inside $U$ and $F(x,y)<0$ outside. The unit normal would be $\nu(x,y)=-\nabla F(x,y)/\|\nabla F(x,y)\|=(x,y)$. (If $y>0$, $U$ is defined by $-y+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}>0$, hence the need to "reorient axes".) [...]

Comment: If $k$ is a positive even integer, the set $U = \{(x, y) : |x|^{k+1} + |y|^{k+1} < 1\}$ has boundary of class $C^{k}$, but not of class $C^{k+1}$: For instance, near $(0, 1)$, the boundary of $U$ is the graph $y = \sqrt[k+1]{1 - |x|^{k+1}}$, and the radicand $1 - |x|^{k+1} = 1 - |x|x^{k}$ is of class $C^{k}$ but not of class $C^{k+1}$. This should be a suitable computational example (though the formula for $\nu$ probably isn't very nice).

Comment: What it means by relabelling and reorienting in definition? What are the operations allowed? Is rotation reflections are allowed? .pleasehelp