# Evan's definition of a $C^k$ boundary

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have a question regarding Evan's definition of a boundary of an open set being $C^k$. Please see this [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228731/understanding-the-definition-of-a-set-with-ck-boundary-and-of-the-outward-poi) for Evan's definition.

The high-level description of that definition that I often hear is the following: locally the boundary of $U$ can be written as a $C^k$ function.

However, from Evan's definition, it only states that locally around the boundary of $U$, the set $U$ itself is the super-level set of a $C^k$ function. It doesn't explicitly state that $\partial U$ is actually the local graph of the function $\gamma$. Other definitions that I have come across actually include this as part of the definition.

Therefore, my question is the following: Only using Evan's definition can one prove that $$\partial U\cap B(x^0, r)=\left\{x\in B(x^0, r)\,\vert\,x_n=\gamma(x_1,\dots, x_{n-1})\right\}?$$

One observation is that for $x\in\partial U\cap B(x^0, r)$, it must be that $x_n\le \gamma(x_1,\dots, x_{n-1})$, else it would contradict the fact that $\partial U\cap U = \emptyset$ (since $U$ is open). But must there be equality?

(As a side note, the pictures in the text seem to suggest that the boundary is indeed the local graph of $\gamma$.)

Comment: What is the definition of $\partial U$ known to you? Did you try to apply it?

Comment: @Thomas $\partial U:= \bar{U} \setminus U^{\circ}$, so $\partial{U} = \bar{U} \setminus U$ for open $U$.

Comment: And what happens (what do you get for $\bar U$) if you apply this to $\{(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, x_n)| x_n > \gamma(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1})\}$ with $\gamma$ a continuous function?

Comment: Maybe you also need to recall that $x\in \bar U$ if and only if there is a sequence $x^k  \in U$ converging to $x$ (upper index to avoid confusion with components). So if you have such an $x$, what can you say about the relation between $x_n$ and $\gamma(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1})$?

Comment: @Thomas Oh thank you. To fill in the details, I guess it goes as follows: Note that the map $F$ given by $x\mapsto x_n - \gamma(x_1,\dots, x_{n-1})$ is continuous by the continuity of $\gamma$. Take a $x\in \bar U\cap B(x^0, r)$. Then there exists a sequence $x^k\in U$ s.t. $x^k\rightarrow x$. For large $K$, $x^k\in B(x^0, r)$ for all $k\ge K$. Also, by continuity, $F(x^k)\rightarrow F(x)$. Since $F(x^k)>0$ for all $k\ge K$, it follows that $F(x) \ge 0$. Then, since $\bar{U} = U\cup \partial{U}$, it must be that $F(z)=0$ for all $x\in \partial{U}\cap B(x^0, r)$. Look correct?

Comment: @Thomas If the above is accurate, I guess my question is now the following: Why do many other sources explicitly state this fact as part of the definition even though it is seemingly redundant? Perhaps it is just important to highlight?

Comment: yes, that looks ok. I don't know why authors choose to do this, but probably they just want to have an explicit statement about what $\partial U$ actually is. Actually it is more or less obvious to experienced mathematicians.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. Makes sense. It could be one of those things where the author knows more than the reader.